# why preference is given to left in tree traversal

Tags: c++11, tree, traversal

**why preference is given to left in tree traversal**
In tree traversal we go through left sub-tree then right sub-tree.
why not we directly go through right sub tree? why right sub-tree not taken in consideration?

Comment: This question is vague. Which traversal are you referring to? How did you conclude that it does not take the right-tree into consideration? Please provide a reference to what you seem to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link[***click here***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) for more details

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Although links can be helpful, your answer should include the essence of the answer. Please quote (using quote format) the relevant part inside your answer.